# WebClient DownloadFileAsync throwing random (504) Gateway Timeout

Tags: c#, vb.net, webclient

I am facing a mysterious issue at one of my client site.
I am downloading a file from AWS S3 location using a signed url having expiration of 30 minutes. Although it works fine everywhere, one client has reported (504) Gateway Timeout issue while downloading file and that too comes once in a blue moon.

I am using the below VB.Net code to download the file

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading

Public Class DownloadFile

    Dim _downloadCompletedEvent As ManualResetEventSlim
    Dim _cts As New CancellationTokenSource()
    Dim _maxWaitTimeForFileDownload As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
    Dim _lastProgressedChangedTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

    Private Sub DownloadFile(ByVal url As String)
        Console.WriteLine("File download started...")

        _downloadCompletedEvent = New ManualResetEventSlim(False)
        Using client = New Net.WebClient()
            AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc_DownloadProgressChanged
            AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc_DownloadFileCompleted

            Dim urlIdentifier = New Uri(url)
            Dim temp_filepath = Path.GetTempFileName
            Try
                'DownloadFile will only show progress in Async mode so using ManualResetEventSlim to wait
                client.DownloadFileAsync(urlIdentifier, temp_filepath)
                Dim isDownloadSuccessful As Boolean = _downloadCompletedEvent.Wait(_maxWaitTimeForFileDownload, _cts.Token)
                If Not isDownloadSuccessful Then
                    'Timeout occured
                    Dim msg = String.Format("Unable to download File in {0} minutes. Seems to be some issue in internet connectivity so aborting download.", _maxWaitTimeForFileDownload.Minutes)
                    Console.WriteLine(msg)
                End If
            Finally
                _downloadCompletedEvent.Dispose()
                client.CancelAsync()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub wc_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Dim progressChangedTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        'Show progress at a defined interval
        If (progressChangedTime - _lastProgressedChangedTime).TotalSeconds > 2 Then
            _lastProgressedChangedTime = progressChangedTime

            Dim dataReceivedInMb = Math.Round((e.BytesReceived / 1024 / 1024), 2)
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received: " & dataReceivedInMb.ToString())
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub wc_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("File download failed. Error occured while downloading file.")
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & e.Error.Message)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("100% | File download completed.")
        End If

        _downloadCompletedEvent.Set()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CancelDownload()
        _cts.Cancel()
    End Sub
End Class
```

By looking at the logs below, I can see that no sooner than it started, it throws error (504) Gateway Timeout.

> 12:17:00.300 (INFO)    File download started...
>
> 12:17:00.341 (WARNING) File download failed. Error occured while downloading file.
>
> 12:17:00.341 (WARNING) Unable to download file in 0.0413338 seconds. Error: The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.

Moreover, I have started continous ping at the client site but did not observe any packet drop; thus, there is no problem with the internet connection. Besides, downloading directly from S3, so there should not be any problem from the server side.

I am bewildered that in which case this error could happen?

Within 41ms DownloadFileAsync has stopped downloading the file. I am quite sure that this method would be having some mechanism to handle minor internet glitches.

What should I do to find out the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this options where the first send headers to AWS to keep connection alive.
The second option make .NET to negotiate TLS in 1.1 or 1.2 (maybe AWS refuse connections on TLS 1.0)
After that if you have the same this issue you need to check Proxy, Firewall or other around network.

```
 Using client = ...
      client.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
      System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: I think if that would be the case, then it should not have occurred randomly.

Comment: Have you tried synchronous downloading (just to test them)?
Things that come as a way to find the issue are: thread interruption for some reason, network problem, AWS temporary problem.
Another test to do is to download another file in another domain (a stress test). If have the same issue the problem is around the Client

Comment: I cannot replace the code with synchronous download as I have to show the progress while downloading and cannot do even for testing as I am not allowed to do experiments on a client's machine. Even I agree that this issue has something to do with client's system. There might be an antivirus or some other security software hindering the download at certain times. What I need is just to find it out as the error message '(504) Gateway Timeout' is not useful. I am now thinking to print the downloading file path whenever I get this error and will ask client to download the file manually.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is to poor as message. You might to add a network tracing on app config file. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/a6sbz1dx(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN